# One print statement two variables get printed on two different lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, generator

```
with open("C:\\Users\\Nav\\Desktop\\script\\names.txt", 'r+') as f:
    for x in range (0, 100):
        f_contents = f.readline()
        name = f_contents
        name2 = name
        print(name.lower().replace(" ", "") + "@gmail.com" + "\n")

x = input()
```

With this code, I am trying to read a file with a full name on each line and format it, that works fine but when I add the "@gmail.com" and get it printed out it gets printed to two different lines in the console.

For example, my output is

```
austenrush
@gmail.com

yuvaanduncan
@gmail.com

jawadpatton
@gmail.com

hanifarusso
@gmail.com

kerysbeck
@gmail.com

safiyamcguire
@gmail.com

oluwatobilobamiddleton
@gmail.com
```

while I would like to get:

```
austenrush@gmail.com

yuvaanduncan@gmail.com

jawadpatton@gmail.com

hanifarusso@gmail.com

kerysbeck@gmail.com

safiyamcguire@gmail.com

oluwatobilobamiddleton@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readline` doesn't strip the newline read from the file; you have to do that yourself.

```
    f_contents = f.readline().rstrip("\n")
```

Files are iterable, though, so you don't need to call `readline` explicitly.

```
from itertools import islice


with open("C:\\Users\\Nav\\Desktop\\script\\names.txt", 'r+') as f:
    for f_contents in islice(f, 100):
        name = f_contents.rstrip("\n").lower().replace(" ", "")
        print(name + "@gmail.com" + "\n")

x = input()
```

Comment: when using your code I get an error Exception has occurred: ValueError
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
  File "C:\Users\Nav\Desktop\script\start.py", line 6, in <module>
    for _, f_contents in islice(f, 100):

Comment: Sorry, I was originally going to use `enumerate` before deciding to use `islice`, and forgot to update the target variables. That should just be `for f_contents in ...`.